# Translating multilingual data within database

Tags: database, translation, multilingual

I have a scenario, to test the data coming out from the database (Kognitio) in different languages. In this case, I cannot afford to have multiple database instances per language. Rather, I am looking at an option where I can translate the data stored in the database and can project on the basis of need.

So basically the data is stored on our databases as a plain English words. In my front end, I see the same. But if I need to do some testing for German language on the front end, as it stands, I need to update the complete rows with the help of some external translation tools. This is very tedious since the data volume is huge (In tera bytes) and can’t be done in a shorter time frame.

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

My sincerest apologies if this is vague. But I can certainly improve the question if needed to be

Comment: Have you thought about setting up a translation-table in your database? Fields could be: Original_Value, Translated_Value, Language_Code (DE). Or you can make a column for every Language.

Comment: @etalon11 This is not possible since my DB size is around 3 TB and I cant have another 3 TB/language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options is to have language tables as an extension to the actual data with retaining original keys. So a primary language will go into the core dimension and we will have a table per language as an extension which can be joined back to the original dimensions with the keys.